# SwiftData relationship updated only after app restart

Tags: swiftui, swift-data, swift-data-relationship

I have 2 simple models with relation 1 to many. `CarMake` can have multiple `CarModels` but one CarModel can only belong to one CarMake. Pretty straightforward.

```
@Model
final class CarModel {
    var name: String
    var make: CarMake
    
    init(name: String, make: CarMake) {
        self.name = name
        self.make = make
    }
}

@Model
final class CarMake {
    var name: String
    @Relationship(inverse: \CarModel.make) var models: [CarModel] = []
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

I created a view that will list all `CarMakes` and another that will list `CarModels` from the relationship property of `CarMake` and will also allow me to add a new `CarModel` to `CarMake`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [CarMake]
    
    @State var count: Int = 1

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(item.name) {
                        CarMakeView(make: item)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    addItem(name: "Car Make \(count)")
                    count += 1
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem(name: String) {
        let newItem = CarMake(name: name)
        modelContext.insert(newItem)
    }
}

struct CarMakeView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @State var count: Int = 1
    var make: CarMake
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(make.models) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button {
                addItem(name: "Car Model \(count)")
                count += 1
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem(name: String) {
        let newItem = CarModel(name: name, make: make)
        modelContext.insert(newItem)
    }
}
```

Adding new `CarModel` object to the modelContext, as presented in `private func addItem(name: String)` will not cause the list of `make.models`(the relationship) to update.
The data is added to the database correctly because if I restart the app the list will show all the added `CarModels` from previous app run. Changing screens does not matter, the relationship is not updated until the app is restarted.
Can somebody help me to pin point what I'm doing wrong with this code?

I tried to simply add a new object with a relationship to another object and then list all the objects in 1 to many relationship. I expected data to be available as soon as I updated the database.

Answer (score 1):

This is some kind of bug in SwiftData since you are not doing anything wrong.
The issue is that your `CarMakeView` has a property `make` of type `CarMake` but you are not updating that property directly but via the relationship and this means that the view doesn't see anything dependent being updated and has no reason to update itself.

This is the bug then because `make` is actually updated when a new car model is added but somehow this change to the relationship property isn't observed properly.

There are some workarounds for this:

The one I use if the relationship properties are optional is to append the new `CarModel` object to the `make` property instead because then we update the `make` property directly

```
private func addItem(name: String) {
    let newItem = CarModel(name: name)
    make.models.append(newItem)
}
```

For your case we need to make the relationship property optional in `CarModel` though for this to work

```
@Model
final class CarModel {
    var name: String
    var make: CarMake?

    init(name: String, make: CarMake? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.make = make
    }
}
```

Another solution is make the view update for some other reason, in your example I simply made use of an existing property

```
@State var count: Int = 1
```

and added it to the `body` in a `Text` which will cause the view to redraw

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("\(count)")
        List {
            ForEach(make.models) { item in
            //...
```